# importing .csv file into rails trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, csv

I'm having trouble importing my .csv file into rails (3.2.6). This is my first experience with csv phrasing, I'm a newbie in general. I used Devise to generate the User model, dont know if that has anything to do with this issue. I'm just creating a simple rake task in tasks/import.rake

```
require 'csv'

desc "Import data from csv file"
task :import => :environment do

CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('db', 'data.csv'), :headers => true) do |row|

    attrs = {
     :first_name             => row[0],
     :last_name              => row[1],
     :email                  => row[2],
     :street_address         => row[3],
     :city                   => row[4],
     :state                  => row[5],
     :zip                    => row[6],
    }

    user = User.new(attrs)

    if user.save
      puts "Saved user #{attrs.inspect}"
    else
      puts "Unable to save user #{attrs.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```

I run`$: rake import`

And i get:

```
Unable to save user {:first_name=>"jane", :last_name=>"joe", :email=>"557@djh.com", street_address=>"38776 main", :city=>"los angeles", :state=>"ca", :zip=>"90887"}
Unable to save user {:first_name=>"bob", :last_name=>"billy", :email=>"7663@top.com",:street_address=>"5958 left", :city=>"los angeles", :state=>"ca", :zip=>"98768"}
Unable to save user {:first_name=>"jill", :last_name=>"jilly", :email=>"5857@joc.com", street_address=>"85755 second", :city=>"culver city", :state=>"ca", :zip=>"90332"}
```

Not sure if theres something obvious I'm missing here. It seems pretty straight forward. Thanks for your help!

Comment: just print user.errors or user.errors.messages instead of that message.

Comment: @retro, you should submit that as an answer so I can vote it up.

Comment: yha thanks retro, this absolutely helped.  i found out that "password" could not be blank for the users to be saved. thanks man!

Comment: this is so nice and clean. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Just print user.errors or user.errors.messages instead of that message. You'll see why your model can't be save.